# What does the word "exist" mean as applied to God's existence and the creation?

Tags: nature-of-god, creation, existence-of-god

Nearly all doctrines of creation refer to the word "exist" or "existence" as if all readers knew its meaning. However, if the significance of creation (and the very nature of God) depends on the word "exist", should it really be taken for granted that the hearer or reader automatically knows what this term means?

Factually, what does the word "exist" mean? If there are multiple assigned or possible meanings, what is an overview of Christian doctrines as to its meaning?
Without resorting to any circular definition, what does it mean when applied to various claims about *creation*, *being*, and the nature and existence of God?
For example, when a Christian says that God is "self-existing", what does that phrase mean (again, without any circular definition)?

For example, I can refer to a dictionary that says "exist" means "to have actual being; to be real" (American Heritage 5th ed.). Then I look up "be" and Oxford languages says it simply means "exist". Clearly we are missing something.

What does "exist" mean, when used in the context of creation or the nature of God?

One reason why this question is not purely philosophical is that special pleading is often applied to God and the creation under various theories of theology. For example, many people assert that God "caused causality" or that it "makes no sense" to ask about how God came to be God. If that is so, and if it is a purely philosophical argument, then it wouldn't matter that the subject is God; the exact same logic should apply to any other being or article such as a shoe, but it doesn't. Therefore the special pleading regarding the existence of God and the nature of creation must be addressed within a theological framework or else reconciled on genuine and general philosophical and factual basis. These exceptions must be addressed; no self-respecting philosopher will accept absurdities or special pleading as obviously true.

What is meant when Christians say that God caused things to exist through Creation, or that God is self-existing?

Comment: Should it really be taken for granted that the hearer/reader knows what "walk" means? Or "the"? How is "exist" different? Language has to start *somewhere*. Fortunately, God seems to have Created humans already possessing language.

Comment: @Matthew Language does have to start somewhere. Walking as opposed to non-walking is observable and concrete. Existence is an abstract notion that is difficult to demonstrate precisely in contrast to a hypothetical alternative which is in general unfalsifiable. If one requires unfalsifiability in a contrast to provide definition to something, then no, I don't think we should take for granted that everyone automatically knows what it means. I believe that God created language.

Comment: Yet again, this is all philosophy. This has nothing whatsoever to do with Christianity. Neither one's understanding of creation nor one's own, personal, spiritual apprehension of the Living God depend on the meaning of a word, especially the word 'exist'.

Comment: @NigelJ Christianity comprehends all true and good philosophy. If Christianity cannot define or accept a reasonable definition of its most basic terms, it would be nonsense.
I know it's not nonsense. Hence we actually have to use real words with real, intelligible meanings. Otherwise no one should bother asking any questions, because he can only expect to receive nonsense in reply. That might be amusing to some, but this is not an entertainment site. This is supposed to be a site that makes true information easier to find.

Comment: The word 'exist' does not occur in the bible. There is no Greek word which bears that concept. I can see no point in this question.

Comment: @NigelJ If this question were about Biblical Hermeneutics, I might agree that the word is not necessarily pertinent to the subject (unless invoked in an interpretation, which it often is). However, as a reminder this post is in the Christianity SE site, and numerous people on this site are seen going around and making assertions that depend on this word, regarding Creation, the nature of God, etc. Therefore defining it is quite germane and appropriate to this site. So far I am hearing the term is either so fundamental that it is trivially defined or else it is irrelevant. Which is it?

Comment: The question should be migrated to [Stack Exchange - English Language and Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions) where there are some 180 questions including the word 'exist' one of which produced an excellent answer [quoting Thomas Aquinas](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/183135/259840).

Comment: @NigelJ Not the same word as the one you linked, see my answer.

Comment: @NigelJ From your account bio: 
"To accurately convey concepts, requires precise language." Is precision of language in defining doctrinal concepts too much to ask?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s not constructive and perhaps would be better on BHSE

Comment: @NigelJ I have not been going around in circles; quite the opposite: I have been asking for ground truth. That is the point. Sir, your arguments that these terms are irrelevant to understanding Christianity (or too simple to bear explanation, on the other hand) are what is circular.
The claim that the Bible does not "peer into the metaphysical" is wholly absurd.
The true meanings of real words are quite ponderable, I assure you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not suitable for this site

Comment: @Lesley Can you explain why you think it is not suitable or how it can be made suitable? It seems like a perfectly germane doctrinal topic to me. I can't see how an honest person can avoid having this question at some point, and it would be incompatible with the Spirit of Christianity to, for example, leave it to a philosophy site or a secular dictionary to provide the answers.

Comment: I do not believe a Christian doctrine on this word exists.  I've read both answers but I fail to see any evidence of a biblical, Christian doctrine.  I think think your question is philosophical in nature, and might be better suited to Biblical Hermeneutics if linked to John 5:26 and/or Hebrews 11:3 where the koine Greek words could be examined.

Comment: @Lesley If there is no Christian doctrine on the meaning of the word "existence", then all doctrines that depend on the meaning of it, including Creation and the nature of God, would be meaningless and subject to endless interpretation and equivocation.
Is that the intent behind our theology? To punt on questions of greatest importance and allow the fundamentals on which we depend for our knowledge of God to be defined and limited by secular philosophers?
If the word is not doctrinal, why is it used in making doctrinal statements?

Comment: Are you looking for a theological or soteriological definition? Maybe that would keep this question in scope ~ if you clearly define what you are aiming at. I suggest that you improve the framing the question. You appear to be quibbling about semantics in a translated language that scripture was translated into.  Your complaint (in comments) about what people do or say on this site is a basis for *a question on Christianity SE META* not the main site.  Also, the English language isn't computer code. As I think you are aware, words can have multiple senses and meanings.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I am looking for a universal definition that will suit all needs, and most especially be able to be understood by people trying to appreciate Christianity's most basic beliefs of Creation and in the nature of God. Definitions that vary substantially based on the lens one wears would not be meaningful in bringing about unity or intelligibility. This is about basic truth claims and comprehensibility.
The meaning of semantics is "meaning", and I would suggest that is pretty meaningful. Since people say this all the time and are not understood, it's clear more clarity is needed.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I am aware that words have multiple senses and meanings, hence the great need to undo the Babel effect and restore intelligibility, sensibility, communication and therefore enable civility between beings.

Comment: *I am looking for a universal definition* ... Then you are, to use an old sailor's expression,  pissing up a rope as the linked Q&A at English SE demonstrated.  In a less jocular sense, you have now supported the comment that this question, as you have presented it, is not a good fit for this site.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast The meanings of words intended to convey Gospel concepts is 100% a good fit for this site, unless all the content of this site is relegated to mere fiction, fairy tales and entertainment.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The word "exist" does not occur anywhere in the KJV Bible.

From Oxford Languages, an etymology of the word "exist" is as follows:
[image: exist word origin]

The logical construction means "To set up, stand up or cause to stand out". This is its factual meaning.
It does not mean "to cause to become real or to begin to be" or "to enter or be in a state of being as opposed to non-being or nothingness".

The present common usage of "exist" as meaning "to have actual being/to be real" is not native; it is an ignorant corruption of the language. It appears for all intents to be an interpolation designed for a case of special pleading.
The closest thing in Scriptural language to the purported sense of the word "exist" in Scripture might be [Hebrews 11:3](https://godrules.net/library/kjvstrongs/kjvstrongsheb11.htm):

> Through faith we understand that the worlds were framed by the word of God, so that things which are seen were not made of things which do appear.

The writer of Hebrews distinguishes lexically between objects that are made (and therefore seen), and things which "do not appear" (literally, that are not brought forth into the light, or are not perceptibly luminescent).
The phrase "bring to light" is often used as a synonym for revelation.
An object that "exists" stands up or stands out and may easily be seen; it makes itself perceptible distinctly from something that does not stand up or stand out. Our English use of the term "outstanding" conveys this idea, that what stands out is easily seen.

God being "self-existing" therefore literally means that He stands up and/or stands out on His own power. Taken idiomatically, one meaning is that He has life in Himself. John 5:26 states that this power is given from the Father to His Son:

> "For as the Father hath life in himself, even so gave he to the Son also to have life in himself"

God is outstanding and upstanding. He has life and integrity in Himself. He is able to stand on His own two feet. He is not only in the light, He is the Source of light. What does not or cannot stand? Dead things. What is not in the light? Imperceptible things, dark things. Are they not real? We cannot falsify that they are real, because a lack of perception on our part does not imply a lack of real being.

The word "exist" apparently has nothing to do with "real being" or lack thereof, other than to say that a thing that "exists" stands up or stands out.
But the word cannot be used to prove the contrary, that a thing that does not stand out does not "exist" in the modern sense, or have real being, merely because we do not see it, as the writer of Hebrews declares. Many invisible or mortally unperceived things are nonetheless real.

In connection to creation, as the writer of Hebrews says, things can be made more apparent from things which were not apparent, or God can form life from non-life, but notably nothing in Scripture implies ex-nihilo, which is an ex post facto interpretation applied to the Scriptural account of Creation.
This is consonant with the Hebrew word [bārā'](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lexicon/h1254/kjv/wlc/0-1/) used in the Creation account, which means to "shape, form, fashion, create, carve out", which are among the primary non-circular definitions given to the term.

There are also multiple different types of "be" verbs in many languages, the semantic distinctions of which are often lost in English. For example, very basically, Spanish *ser* typically describes a permanent nature of being, *estar* describes a temporary status, and *haber* (roughly, "have") when used as an impersonal verb means "there is". All three of these are commonly projected down to a single "be" verb in English, resulting in potentially significant loss of important information. This is true of many richer languages. Therefore it cannot be trivially assumed that when someone says that something "is", "exists" or "came into being" that what is described is literal exnihilation (a term I had to invent to express the idea of something arising from nothing--but even then I cobbled it together out of existing word parts, not out of nothing), rather than a status change, including to its perceptibility. Came into being what? Sad? Angry? Happy? Virtuous? Organized? For speakers of more descriptive languages than modern English, such questions are natural, not something presupposed to have been answered already without further information. The writer of Hebrews answers that Creation may have consisted at least in part of a status change from things being unseen to being seen.
The word "exist" by definition denotes a change in status, not a discontinuity of identity or a change of permanent, real being.

It *is* something of a challenge to write this without circularly injecting the word "exist" to try to explain things away because the present use of the term has become so entrenched and so easy to take for granted, despite the observation that it is not an accurate rendering and thus this difficulty is proof of serious degradation of our language and a circular devolution of communication, which breeds contention so long as it remains unresolved. But a circular definition would be invalid.

Interestingly the the Hebrew term ["hāyâ"](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lexicon/h1961/kjv/wlc/0-1/) used in the Creation account (as in, "let there be light") can be translated, "to arise, to stand, to abide". In a curious coincidence, it has very similar pronunciation to the Spanish conjugation of *haber* having nearly identical meaning in this context. So it is entirely possible that the word *"exist"* is apropos in the context of Creation, but only in the original sense and not in the modern, degraded sense.

Comment: All of this is expressed as the writer's _own opinion_. Language and meaning are not what an individual supposes it to be or what they want it to be or what they assert it to be. One requires to support _every single detail_ from learned and studied and peer-reviewed and qualified _authority_.

Comment: @NigelJ The meaning of the word "exist" is well-defined, concrete, and factual. This is not a matter of opinion. Some examples are given to show how using the actual definition of the term eliminates many otherwise unresolvable quandaries and contradictions.
Does "learned" mean "You're not allowed to ask those questions" or "You're not allowed to use factual definitions"?
If you have a specific linguistic factual or linguistic criticism or correction, please offer it. Otherwise please do not perform the disservice of calling a factual answer an "opinion".

Comment: @NigelJ "Language and meaning are not what an individual supposes it to be or what they want it to be or what they assert it to be" - I agree, which is why I used a real-world etymology instead of referencing someone's made-up, confused or pejorated assignment of meaning.

Comment: I like your answer since it makes many important distinctions that are part and parcel of Christian's theological discussion regarding BOTH the existence of God AND how creatures came to be created by this self-existing God: make vs. exist, Bible references, linguistic history, etc. But you don't use those distinctions to give a proper answer to your own Q, because Christianity DOES have a definite position (ex. classical theism) regarding the relationship between the linguistic meaning "exist", our cognition of the being we call "God", and the character "God" in the Bible. So I didn't vote.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple Could you clarify? What exactly is the answer missing? I don't have to cite extra-biblical creeds or interpretations in order to summarize definitively what true Christianity has to say on the subject.

Answer (score 4):

According to the empirical studies of the [Natural Semantic Metalanguage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_semantic_metalanguage) (NSM) project, human language and thinking has basic core concepts, also called semantic primes, that cannot be reduced to others, and are shared by all natural human languages. The list of NSM primes has been empirically developed over more than 40 years as a growing number of languages from all major language families have been studied, such that it is reasonable to conclude that these primes are found in all natural languages. While NSM is contentious within linguistics, I think it is a helpful way of thinking about human cognition, and I think it has potential to help us communicate theology effectively.

Existence is one of the core concepts, represented by the prime THERE IS (X). This means existence can't be effectively defined - the circle of definitions stops with THERE IS. But we don't need to define it further than that, because everyone already understands what it means.

Philosophical discussions about "existence" usually get into edge cases like unicorns or even logical contradictions like four sided triangles or married bachelors. This doesn't negate that the basic concept of existence is simple and shared by all of us, it just means that there are more complicated derivative concepts. The NSM is still using language, which means it is contextual. And so someone might still use the prime THERE IS in a philosophical debate over unicorns, but context lets us know the connotations of that differ from the basic statement that "there is a god" or "there is an earth".

---

When we apply existence to God there are several doctrines we could also explain with NSM (these are my own NSM explications):

The existence of God:
 There is God

God is un-created:
 It is not like this:
  At one time there is not God
  Someone did something
  Because of this, there is God

The self-existence (aseity) of God:
 It is not like this:
  Because of someone or something, there is God

---

But then I remembered that the creator of the NSM, Anna Wierzbicka, actually published a whole book exploring theology and the story of the Bible using NSM and her "Minimal English". This Minimal English is based on the NSM (and so has a more rigorous theoretical foundation than other versions of "basic English"), but with additional [semantic molecules](https://intranet.secure.griffith.edu.au/schools-departments/natural-semantic-metalanguage/what-is-nsm/semantic-molecules). This is an interesting way of doing theology that is both very clear, without traditional jargon, and also much more easily translatable. And she does a much better job of it that I do!

Here are parts of the first two sections of her "The Story of God and People", from [What Christians Believe](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/43093169-what-christians-believe) (pages 69-70):

> ### 1. God
>
> There is someone not like people.
> This someone is someone above people; this someone is above everything.
> This someone is now, always was, and always will be. This someone is everywhere.
> There is no one else like this someone.
> God is this someone.
> People can't see God; at the same time, people can know some things about God.
> They can know these things because god wants it.
> People can know that it is like this:
>  God is good.
>  If God wants something, it is something good, if God does something, it is something good.
>  If God wants something to happen, it can happen because of this.
>  If God says about something: "I want it to happen," it happens.
>  If God says about something: "It is like this," it is true.
>  God knows everything.
>
> At the same time, people can know that it is like this:
>  God knows all people.
>  God feels something very good toward all people.
>  God wants to do good things for all people.
>  God wants to speak to all people.
>  All people can know God, God wants it.
>  All people can live with God, God wants it.
>
> ...
>
> ### 2. The world exists because God wants it to exist
>
> It is like this now:
>  There are many people living on earth, there are many things on earth, many things are happening on earth.
>  There is the sky above the earth, there is light, there is the sun, there is the moon, there are stars.
> It is like this because God wants it to be like this.
> It wasn't always like this. A very very long time ago, it was like this:
>  There was no earth, there was no sky, there was no light;
>  there are no places as there are now,
>  There were no people, there was nothing anywhere,
>  nothing was happening anywhere.
>  There was God.
>
> Before there was anything anywhere, God said something.
> God said:
>  "I want there to be places of some kinds;
>  I want some things to be happening in those places."
> When God said this, something happened, it happened as God wanted.
> God said, "I want there to be light." When god said this, there was light.
> God said, "This is very good."
> After this, many other things were happening for a very long time, as God wanted.
> After some time, it was like this:
>  There were places of many kinds,
>   many things were happening in these places.
>  There was the earth, there was the sky, there was the sun, there was the moon, there were stars.
>  It was like this because God wanted it to be like this.
> God said: "This is very good."
>
> ...

It's such a different way of thinking about and doing theology, that I'd recommend everyone give this book a read, just to see how our theological language could be different!